# calculating ot hours with if statement

Tags: javascript, php, html, if-statement

i want to calculate ot hours in javascript but it seems like it's a very long code. not for whole hours, when it comes to half hours it gets complicated. this is my code so far.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#intime,#outtime').on('input', function() {
        // declare variables
        var intime = new moment($("#intime").val(), 'HH:mm:ss'); // get value of intime
        var outtime= new moment($("#outtime").val(), 'HH:mm:ss'); 

        var startTime = new moment("08:00:00", 'HH:mm:ss');
        var halfDay = new moment("12:30:00", 'HH:mm:ss');
        var wholeDay = new moment("18:00:00", 'HH:mm:ss');


        var othours = 0; // declare day as 0
        /*AFTER 18.00*/ 
        if (moment(intime).hour() == 8 && (moment(outtime).hour() == 18 && moment(outtime).minute() == 30)) {
            othours = 0.5;
        }
        else if (moment(intime).hour() == 8 && (moment(outtime).hour() == 19 && moment(outtime).minute() == 30)) {
            othours = 1.5;
        }
        else if (moment(intime).hour() == 8 && (moment(outtime).hour() == 20 && moment(outtime).minute() == 30)) {
            othours = 2.5;
        }
        else if (moment(intime).hour() == 8 && (moment(outtime).hour() == 21 && moment(outtime).minute() == 30)) {
            othours = moment(outtime).hour() && moment(outtime).minute() - moment(wholeDay).hour() && moment(wholeDay).minute();
        }
        else if (moment(intime).hour() == 8 && (moment(outtime).hour() == 22 && moment(outtime).minute() == 30)) {
            othours = 4.5;
        }
        else if (moment(intime).hour() == 8 && (moment(outtime).hour() == 23 && moment(outtime).minute() == 30)) {
            othours = 5.5;
        }
        else if (moment(intime).hour() == 8 && (moment(outtime).hour() == 00 && moment(outtime).minute() == 30)) {
            othours = 6.5;
        }
        /*BEFORE 8.00*/
        else if (moment(intime).hour() == 8 && (moment(outtime).hour() == 00 && moment(outtime).minute() == 30)) {
            othours = 6.5;
        }
        else if (moment(intime).hour() == 8 && (moment(outtime).hour() == 00 && moment(outtime).minute() == 30)) {
            othours = 6.5;
        }

        /*WHOLE HOURS*/
        else if (moment(intime).hour() == 8 && moment(outtime).hour() > 18) {
            othours = moment(outtime).hour() - moment(wholeDay).hour();
        }
        else if (moment(intime).hour() < 8 && moment(outtime).hour() > 18) {
            othours = moment(startTime).hour() - moment(intime).hour() + moment(outtime).hour() - moment(wholeDay).hour();
        }
        else if (moment(intime).hour() < 8 && moment(outtime).hour() == 18) {
            othours = moment(startTime).hour() - moment(intime).hour();
        }
      $("#othours").val(othours);

    });
})
</script>
```

is there any shorter method or do i have to continue like this for other half hours also? as in if intime= 6.30 and outtime= 19.30, the othours should be 3hours.

[image]

this is my output. i want to calculate OT hours when i enter in-time and out-time

Comment: what do you want in your output it's very complex your code. i can't understand what do you want ...

Comment: For starters don't call the same functions over and over when you can store them in simple variables once

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to get the OT hours automatically @Picard

Comment: what is ot hrs and how are you trying to calculate it?

Comment: ot means overtime. btw i got what i was looking for. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#intime,#outtime').on('input', function() {
        // declare variables
        var intime = new moment($("#intime").val(), 'HH:mm:ss'); // get value of intime
        var outtime= new moment($("#outtime").val(), 'HH:mm:ss'); 

        var othours = 0; // declare day as 0

        othours = moment.utc(moment(outtime,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(intime,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH")
        if(othours>10)
            $("#othours").val(othours-10);
        else
            $("#othours").val("Whole Day not work");

    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: i wanted to calculate minutes also. thanks anyway :)

Comment: intime = moment(intime).add(10, 'hours');

othours = moment.utc(moment(outtime,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(intime,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm");

$("#othours").val(othours);

Answer (score 0):

this works with what i was looking for.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#intime,#outtime').on('input', function() {
        // declare variables
        var intime = new moment($("#intime").val(), 'HH:mm:ss'); // get value of intime
        var outtime= new moment($("#outtime").val(), 'HH:mm:ss'); 

        var startTime = new moment("08:00:00", 'HH:mm:ss');
        var wholeDay = new moment("18:00:00", 'HH:mm:ss');

        var othours = 0; // declare othours as 0

        if (moment(intime).hour() == 8 && (moment(outtime).hour() > 18 && moment(outtime).minute() == 30)) {
            othours = moment(outtime).hour() - moment(wholeDay).hour() + 0.5;
        }
        else if (moment(intime).hour() == 8 && moment(outtime).hour() > 18) {
            othours = moment(outtime).hour() - moment(wholeDay).hour();
        }
        else if ((moment(intime).hour() < 8 && moment(intime).minute() == 30) && (moment(outtime).hour() > 18 && moment(outtime).minute() == 30)) {
            othours = moment(startTime).hour() - moment(intime).hour() + moment(outtime).hour() - moment(wholeDay).hour();
        }
        else if ((moment(intime).hour() < 8 && moment(intime).minute() == 30) && moment(outtime).hour() == 18) {
            othours = moment(startTime).hour() - moment(intime).hour() - 0.5;
        }
        else if (moment(intime).hour() < 8 && moment(outtime).hour() == 18) {
            othours = moment(startTime).hour() - moment(intime).hour();
        }
        else if ((moment(intime).hour() < 8 && moment(intime).minute() == 30) && moment(outtime).hour() > 18) {
            othours = moment(startTime).hour() - moment(intime).hour() + moment(outtime).hour() - moment(wholeDay).hour() - 0.5;
        }
        else if (moment(intime).hour() < 8 && (moment(outtime).hour() > 18) && moment(outtime).minute() == 30) {
            othours = moment(startTime).hour() - moment(intime).hour() + moment(outtime).hour() - moment(wholeDay).hour() + 0.5;
        }

        $("#othours").val(othours);

    });
})
</script>
```